# CompletionStage: Why is allOf or anyOf defined in CompletableFuture

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have a framework that uses the interface [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) and I'm curious why the helper methods `anyOf` or `allOf` found in [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) are defined there.

Seems like they should be operating on the interfaces rather than the implementation ?

I'm quite dissatisfied with the CompletionStage interface thus far.
Are there other Java libraries that are CompletionStage compliant but a different superset interface someone can recommend?

Or perhaps some library written with additional helper methods for working with CompletionStage ?

Comment: The quora answer https://www.quora.com/Java-programming-language-Why-is-allOf-or-anyOf-defined-in-CompletableFuture mentions that allOf and anyOf are static and cannot be overriden by subclasses, and thus get special (safer) treatment

Answer (score 3):

If all you want, is a method providing the same `anyOf` and `allOf` functionality for objects of the type `CompletionStage`, you can simply resort to [`toCompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#toCompletableFuture--):

```
public static CompletionStage<Object> anyOf(CompletionStage<?>... css) {
    return CompletableFuture.anyOf(Arrays.stream(css)
        .map(CompletionStage::toCompletableFuture).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new));
}
public static CompletionStage<Void> allOf(CompletionStage<?>... css) {
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(Arrays.stream(css)
        .map(CompletionStage::toCompletableFuture).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new));
}
```

Comment: My question is more as to why are those functions not even in the interface. Seems like a mistake on the JDK developers.

Comment: Since that is an optional method, it is inappropriate for a framework to assume.

Comment: @BenManes What's optional ? They included that in the CompletableFuture implementation it just seems incorrect

Comment: "A CompletionStage implementation that does not choose to interoperate with others may throw {@code UnsupportedOperationException}." For example, until recently Scala's Future adapters did not support this method. It is only safe when you produced the future.

Comment: @BenManes: But several CompletableFuture methods do call toCompletableFuture anyway, like applyToEither...(), acceptEither...(), thenCombine...(), thenAccept...() and so on. They call it on the CompletionStage argument whose implementation is unknown. Why would allOf() and anyOf() be special cases?

Comment: @tkruse true, I think it was improper for it to be optional, and in fact no longer is in JDK10. It used to state `that does not choose to interoperate with others` to provides leeway of major incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've come up with

```
/**
 * A class with several helper methods for working with {@link CompletionStage}
 */
public class CompletionStages {


    public static CompletionStage<Object> anyOf(CompletionStage... completionStages) {
        if (completionStages == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must pass a non-null argument for completionStages");
        }
        if (completionStages.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must pass a non-empty argument for completionStages");
        }

        CompletableFuture result = new CompletableFuture();
        for(CompletionStage completionStage : completionStages) {
            completionStage.thenAccept( r -> result.complete(r));
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static CompletionStage<Void> allOf(CompletionStage... completionStages) {
        if (completionStages == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must pass a non-null argument for completionStages");
        }
        if (completionStages.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must pass a non-empty argument for completionStages");
        }

        CompletionStage result = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        for(int i = 0; i < completionStages.length; i++) {
            CompletionStage curr = completionStages[i];
            result = result.thenAcceptBoth(curr, (o, o2) -> {});
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```