# How to call parameterless function after CompletableFuture.allOf

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have an async function in java.  I want to make async calls to a number of APIs (in parallel) then create a response.  Since I need the different results, I though to save them in the class. I have helper functions to make the calls to the external APIs (classes with a call function which return `CompletableFuture<List<T>>`). I can do this like this:

```
public class MyAction{
   private List<Bar> bars;
   private List<Baz> bazs;

   public CompletableFuture<Foo> run() {
       CompletableFuture<Void> fetchBars = new BarFetcher().call().thenAccept(this::populateBars);
       CompletableFuture<Void> fetchBazs = new BazFetcher().call().thenAccept(this::populateBazs);

       return CompletableFuture.allOf(fetchBars, fetchBazs).thenApply(this::getFoo);
   }

   private void populateBars(final List<Bar> bars) {
       this.bars = bars;
   }

   private void populateBaz(final List<Baz> bazs) {
       this.bazs = bazs;
   }

   private Foo getFoo(final Void dummy) {
       return new Foo(bars, bazs);
   }
}
```

But I had to add an unnecessary parameter (`final Void dummy`) to the `getFoo` function to make it work.  Can I avoid this?  if should really just be `getFoo()` not `getFoo(final Void dummy)`. Is there any way to wait for multiple futures to complete and then chain in another function without passing it directly any data?

Note: The example only has two initial calls to fetch data (`fetchbars` and `fetchBazs`) before the final processing (`getFoo`).  However, I actually will have more than two.  I currently have three, but it may grow by one or two more.  I would like to run all the initial calls in parallel, then the final processing once all have completed.

Answer (score 3):

Use the right tool for the job. To combine two futures, just use

```
public CompletableFuture<Foo> run() {
    return new BarFetcher().call().thenCombine(new BazFetcher().call(),
        (List<Bar> bars, List<Baz> bazs) -> new Foo(bars, bazs));
}
```

or even simpler

```
public CompletableFuture<Foo> run() {
    return new BarFetcher().call().thenCombine(new BazFetcher().call(), Foo::new);
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I want. However, I had simplified my problem slightly in the example code - I actually have >2 calls I want to make to fetch the data i will then work with :).  Currently three, but i expect it to grow.  i googled a bit and couldn't find any clean ways to generalise this.  There was some examples of chaining with `Pair<>` as the second param in the combines, but it got messy.  Also, I want to run all the population requests in parallel, not run two and when they are done a third and so on.

Is it possible to generalise this to more than two parallel calls initially?

Comment: When you use `thenCombine`, the futures *are* already running in parallel. The syntax does not scale well with a growing number of futures to combine, so you may prefer using `allOf` and live with the little nuisance of having to drop a `Void` parameter in the adapter function (compare to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005471/2711488)). For inputs of the same type, you could use the alternative `allOf` implementation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49939668/2711488), which returns a `CompletionStage<List<T>>`.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I'll stick with what I have for now - as long as it's a private function I can live with the `Void dummy`.

Answer (score 0):

you could change the use of method reference to a lambda as follows:

```
return CompletableFuture.allOf(fetchBars, fetchBazs)
                        .thenApply(e -> getFoo());
```

then you don't have to introduce a dummy parameter.

---

Note, I am not that familiar with the `CompletableFuture` API so, there may be more suitable solutions out there.

Comment: It is still there, just that you don't take it :)

Comment: @NiVeR true but isn't this what the OP is pretty much asking for "But I had to add an unnecessary parameter (final Void dummy) to the getFoo function to make it work. Can I avoid this? "  so they can avoid having to create a dummy parameter by not using a method reference. anyway, I had a feeling there are better solutions out there which I believe #Holger has just posted.

Comment: Yeah, not sure.  it makes the `getFoo()` definition cleaner, if it would ever be called from anywhere else.  But given that it's private (for a reason - it will fail unless the population has run first) then it probably won't be :)  But at the cost of introducing an otherwise unnecessary lambda